# SP2013 Workflow that Iterates through List

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want my workflow to perform its steps for each item in my list.

Is there an easy way to do this? Currently when I start the workflow manually, it only runs on that particular item.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one time activity you could probably try a PowerShell script that would start the workflow for all items for a list.

Below is the code snippet that could help you out. Please test the script and use as i dont have a setup to test this on right now.

```
$siteURL = <site_url>
$listName = <list_name>
$site = Get-Spsite $siteURL
$web = $site.RootWeb
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$manager = $site.WorkFlowManager

foreach($item in $list.Items){
   //select your workflow here
    $association=$list.WorkFlowAssociations[0]
    $data=$association.AssociationData
    $wf=$manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$association,$data,$true)
}
```

Comment: I am not a SP admin, I simply manage our team site. I don't think I would have rights to run any scripts .

Comment: Without c# or Powershell you wouldn't be able to do this. There is one way that comes to mind which is very dirty and probably not recommended. Since this is a list I am hoping you can open the list in an "excel style" edit mode. Add a dummy single line of text column and make the workflow run on item modification. Now once that's done, you can add a single character in the column and drag the cell to duplicate across all rows and save. Viola! Your workflow now runs for all cells. Remember, modified name will change to your name. Also remember to delete the column later ;)

Comment: That's a good workaround. The only downside to that is that I will be modifying each item, so I would lose that bit of original metadata...the actual person who last modified.